# Перевод из imageView в File

Tags: java, android, файлы, email, imageview

Пытаюсь отправить изображение в android.
В java делаю так.

```
BufferedImage bi; // в этой переменной у меня уже есть изображение
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("mtom", ".png");
  String format =".png";
  ImageIO.write(bi, format, tempFile);
 DataSource source = new FileDataSource(tempFile);
 attachBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
 attachBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
```

Как сделать также но с imageView?
Если точнее как записать из переменной картинку из image в класс File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageView` при выводе изображения выводит его как `Bitmap`, свойства которого зависят от конкретного девайса - вернее от экрана девайса.

Остается взять `Bitmap` из кэша и записать его в файл:

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();  //удостовериться, что imageView будет записан в кэш
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache(); //взять битмап из кэша
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); //буфер куда сохраняем битмап
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes); //пишем в виде JPEG
file = createTempFile("mtom", ".jpg");
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
fo.close();
```

Comment: В файле будет картинка или последовательность байт?